# Firebase user is authenticated, so why is uploading to storage denied?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

In a react-native project, I'm using *both* `react-native-firebase` and the `firebase` sdk. 
`react-native-firebase` does not allow use of firebase storage to upload image blobs, which is why im using the vanilla Firebase javascript SDK to do this part. For distinction's sake, in my code & this post, im identifying the firebase javascript sdk as 'FIREBASE', and the `react-native-firebase` as 'firebase'.

I had to initialize my firebase app (even though `react-native-firebase` doesn't require this for its function, `firebase` does), App.js constructor & imports:

```
 import * as React from 'react';
 import AppNavigation from './src/navigation';
 import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
 import { store, persistor } from './src/store/index.js';
 import firebase from 'firebase/app';
 import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
 export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
     super(props);
     const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: '{apiKey}',
        authDomain: 'project-ID.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://project-ID.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'project-ID',
        storageBucket: 'project-ID.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '9999999999'
     };
     if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
     }
  }
```

I implement firebase *and* FIREBASE in an action (firebase for auth/firestore, and FIREBASE for storage):

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import * as FIREBASE from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;

export const registerUser = (registration) => {
    const { email, pass, username, img } = registration;
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.REGISTER_USER });
        console.log('starting registration process...');
        // check username is unique
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .where('username', '==', username)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.empty !== true) {
                    // back to registration form
                    registrationFail(dispatch, 'Username already taken. Try again.');
                    console.log("Registrant's username already exists");
                } else {
                    console.log('Registrants username is unique');
                    // continue with registration
                    firebase
                        .auth()
                        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                        .then((userCredential) => {
                            // successful user creation, now authenticated
                            // write to img storage
                            uploadImg(dispatch, img, userCredential.user.uid)
                                .then((imgUrl) => {
                                    // on success, write to firestore
                                    uploadImgSuccess(dispatch, 'Profile image upload successful...');
                                    // write rest of data to firestore
                                        firebase
                                            .firestore()
                                            .collection('users')
                                            .add({
                                                createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                                                username: email,
                                                uid: userCredential.user.uid,
                                                profileImg: imgUrl,
                                                email: email,
                                            })
                                            .catch((err) => {
                                                console.log('Registration failed. Error: ' + err.message);
                                                registrationFail(dispatch, err.message);
                                            });
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch((err) => {
                                    // Image Profile NOT Uploaded
                                    uploadImgFail(dispatch, err);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            // unsuccessful user creeation
                            registrationFail(dispatch, err.message);
                        });
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => registrationFail(dispatch, err.message));
    };
};
const uploadImg = async (dispatch, uri, uid, mime = 'image/png') => {
    console.log('Starting image upload...');
    dispatch({ type: types.UPLOAD_IMG, info: 'Uploading profile image...' });
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    let uploadBlob = null;
    // let downloadPath = '';
    const imageRef = FIREBASE.storage().ref(uid).child('profileImg');
    fs
        .readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
            return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
        })
        .then((blob) => {
            uploadBlob = blob;
            return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
        })
        .then(() => {
            uploadBlob.close();
            return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        })
        .then((url) => {
            console.log('Returning Download URL: ' + url);
            uploadImgSuccess(dispatch, 'Image upload successful...');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            uploadImgFail(dispatch, 'Image  upload failed: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
};
```

but when I go through `uploadImg()`, I get an error:

```
{ 
  "code_": "storage/unauthorized", 
  "message":"Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'someReference/someChild', 
  "serverResponse":{"Code":403, "message": "permission denied."}
}
```

Here is Firestore rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is Storage rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand what's going on or why. The user is authenticated during react-native-firebase's `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and is even allowed to upload data to Firestore. My only guess is this possibly has something to do either with using both firebase & FIREBASE, or with the way i've setup firebase with FIREBASE. I've used both together in a previous test project and it worked successfully with the help of a forked project `rn-fetch-blob` (the maintained version of `react-native-fetch-blob`), however I had no security rules in place bc of testing, so...

Any ideas for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have guessed it right, your `FIREBASE` instance is unaware of the auth being done by the `firebase` since the `firebase` handles the native aspects and FIREBASE is just a JS thing. so both of the instances have their own lives and their own prospects with own attributes to identify the user and provide authorization.

To resolve this, try authorizing the user either by the vanilla JS SDK or use the rn-firebase for the whole task.
I would recommend using `react-native-firebase`, it has good support for entire firebase stack.
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/storage/reference/storage

**EDIT:**

Vanilla JS firebase SDK should not be used in mobile applications especially when it is native since firebase will treat the client as web client and going forward you will not be able to leverage all possible mobile things from firebase such as dynamic links, push notifications and analytics.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: trust me I dont want to use the JS sdk at all, but there is no method binding for `react-native-firebase` to `put()` files into storage...im kind of confused as to that seems to be a significant part of firebase storage...

Comment: @Jim I guess this might help you. 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/storage/reference/Reference#putFile